# JSON_decode problem with array posted to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, json

I am certain I am making a simple mistake... but simply can't find it.

Ultimately I am posting a JSON array from an Android app (that part is working), but for the time being I am simply testing between two PHP pages (1: test PHP page with basic form, and 2: the CodeIgniter final destination)  Here is what I have:

At the form page:

```
<form action="bambooinvoice/index.php/api2/newinvoice/4/0/0" method="post">
    <?php 
        $array = array("items"=>array(
            "taxable"=>1, 
            "quantity"=>1, 
            "amount"=>123.99, 
            "work_description"=>"this is a test"));
        $json = json_encode($array);
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name=json value=<?php $json ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="btnSendForm" value="Send" />
</form>
```

This creates (which looks good to me):

```
{"items":{"taxable":1,"Quantity":1,"amount":123.99,"work_description":"this is a test"}}
```

On the codeIgniter side, I have:

```
$input = $this->input->post('json');
$items = json_decode($input, TRUE);

$amount = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) // In case there are multiple 'items'
{
    $taxable = (isset($item['taxable']) && $item['taxable'] == 1) ? 1 : 0;

    $invoice_items = array(
        'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
        'amount' => $item['amount'],
        'work_description' => $item['work_description'],
        'taxable' => $taxable
    );

    $this->_addInvoiceItem($invoice_items); //simply adding contents to DB
}
```

In the end I receive the error: (i have received numerous errors actually in all my tweaking, but this is the one I can't seem to shake)

```
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Edited - to correct a typo.

Comment: have you tried `var_dump()`ing `$items` and `$json` to ensure they are what you expect them to be?

Comment: You're dumping unescaped `JSON` data to an attribute. I'm assuming this is causing some brokenness in the `DOM`, and the POST data is also broken.

Comment: If is not a typo here, this line ` <input type="hidden" name=json value=<?php $json ?> />` looks wrong to me. you are not echoing the data. it should be `<?=$json?>` or `<?php echo $json?>`

Comment: Yes, thank you for reminding me, I have output'd the various variables.  var_dump($input); = 1  I had seen this previously but thought it meant there was '1' associative array inside the posted JSONObject (ie - 1 'item')... but perhaps I have handled this incorrectly and it is being treated as a bool?

Comment: ...and var_dump($items)=NULL.  This tells me my mistake is between the post on the form side and decode on the service side.

Comment: I 'print_r'ed ($_POST) at the top of my destination page and found it gave me what looks like the appropriate POST information: 
[json] => {"items":"taxable":1,"quantity":1,"amount":123.99,"desc":"test"}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `$this->input->post('items')` when your form is posting a hidden value named `json`.

If you `var_dump($this->input->post('items'))`, it should be `FALSE` or `NULL`.

Try this in your CI script instead:

```
$input = $this->input->post('json'); // not 'items'
$items = json_decode($input, TRUE);

// Rest of your code...
```

That should fix that problem, but you also need to make sure your json data is being sent correctly to begin with! `var_dump($_POST)` should show you if it's making it to your script in one piece.

Comment: Aaaaaarrghh!!!  (sighh...)  It is working just as it should.  Thank you bschaeffer, I can't tell you how much that stupid mistake was irritating me.

Comment: Yeah... those kind of things can be hard to notice because you never think you messed up the "easy part". Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`<input type="hidden" name=json value='<?=$json?>' />`
Or this
`<input type="hidden" name=json value='<?=str_replace('\'', '&#039;', $json)?>' />`

See [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Comment: Thanks, azat.  You are right... I needed to correct this line.  It is now: <input type="hidden" name=json value=<?php echo $json; ?> />

Answer (score 0):

When you encode an assoc. array as JSON it becomes an object and is no longer an array. Now when you decode your JSON php creates objects of your JSON and not an assoc. array.

Comment: No correct.. see this http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php, second parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can change and not use json_encode and use serialize in you array.

Like this in your form:

```
<form action="bambooinvoice/index.php/api2/newinvoice/4/0/0" method="post">
    <?php 
        $array = array("items"=>array(
            "taxable"=>1, 
            "quantity"=>1, 
            "amount"=>123.99, 
            "work_description"=>"this is a test"));
        $json = serialize($array);
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name=json value="<?php echo $json ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="btnSendForm" value="Send" />
</form>
```

This serialize function will create this output:

```
a:1:{s:5:"items";a:4:{s:7:"taxable";i:1;s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:6:"amount";d:123.9899999999999948840923025272786617279052734375;s:16:"work_description";s:14:"this is a test";}}
```

Then in the codeigniter side you can do this:

```
<?php
$input = $this->input->post('json');
$items = unserialize($input);

$amount = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) // In case there are multiple 'items'
{
    $taxable = (isset($item['taxable']) && $item['taxable'] == 1) ? 1 : 0;

    $invoice_items = array(
        'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
        'amount' => $item['amount'],
        'work_description' => $item['work_description'],
        'taxable' => $taxable
    );

    $this->_addInvoiceItem($invoice_items); //simply adding contents to DB
}
?>
```

but be careful, because when you use a foreach with an array who contain more the 1 level.
I hope that this help you.