# How to receive this json data and insert in db

Tags: codeigniter

Post this data from app.how to receive this data in Controller and Insert DB

{
"status": "processing",
"customer_id":"30",
"shipping_address":{
"first_name":"",
"last_name":"",
"address":"",
"city":"",
"state":"",
"postcode":"",
},
"items":[{
"product_id":61,
"quantity": 1
},
{
"product_id":62,
"quantity": 1,

}]
}

Answer (score 1):

To get the data to Controller just use `$this->input->post('name')`;
You can use `json_decode()` function to decode your JSON.

Check out this link : [Json decode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5150489/9809584)

Answer (score 1):

Use json_decode($data,true); in controller. $data could be post data and this will resulting into an array.